# If a cell is positioned between "Cell X" and "Cell Y". Then return "X"

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

Lets say I have 2 (or more) lists below each other, each with a main category. In the adjacent cell I would like to return the category that the list item falls in. As in the below picture explained.

[image: IMG:]

The reason I need this is because I have a media query table with adjacent (in row) formulas. When a row in a table is added or removed, the formulas don't longer match the right rows. I couldn't find a fix, so this would be a fix that I could think of, because there are fixed variables in the table (in the image example the fixed categories would be "vegetables" and "drinks"). Every time a new vegetable or drink is added, the cell in column D  will have the right category.

Thanks a lot for taking the time to reply :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try using the formula below. It checks for cells above the current with a value of "Drinks". If found, then "Drinks" is set for the current row. If not, "Vegetables" is set. Drag it down to fill the other cells.

```
=IF(A2<>"Drinks",IFNA(IF(MATCH("Drinks",$A$1:A1,0)>0,"Drinks"),"Vegetables"),"")
```

[image: IMG:]

Drinks is not set as Vegetables as your example shows.

EDIT: Based on the comments by the OP of 2 more categories, then you need to include more nested IF. I changed the formula to incorporate `TEXTJOIN` function but the logic remains the same. We search the categories from last to first.

```
=IF(ISNUMBER(MATCH(A2,{"Vegetables","Drinks","Countries","Cars"},0)),"",IF(ISNUMBER(FIND("Cars",TEXTJOIN(",",FALSE,$A$1:A1))),"Cars",IF(ISNUMBER(FIND("Countries",TEXTJOIN(",",FALSE,$A$1:A1))),"Countries",IF(ISNUMBER(FIND("Drinks",TEXTJOIN(",",FALSE,$A$1:A1))),"Drinks","Vegetables"))))
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply. In my sheet there are 4 categories. Let's assume there are 2 more categories: 1) Countries: England, Germany, France. 2) Cars: BMW, Ferrari, Mercedes. Would this reasoning of code still work or do we need other logic? I've tried to continue with your line but that doesn't work unfortunately. 
 =IF(A2<>"Drinks";IFNA(IF(MATCH("Drinks";$A$1:A1;0)>0;"Drinks");"Vegetables");"");IF(A2<>"Cars";IFNA(IF(MATCH("Cars";$A$1:A1;0)>0;"Cars");"Vegetables");"");IF(A2<>"Countries";IFNA(IF(MATCH("Countries";$A$1:A1;0)>0;"Countries");"Vegetables");"")

Comment: @Daan If you add more categories, then the formula must be changed to test the added categories. See edit of my answer.